# Should I assign static IP from within or outside DHCP pool

Tags: ip, dhcp

I've setup-up `192.168.55.0` network and set DHCP range from `192.168.55.100` to `192.168.55.200` now I want to assign static IP to my PC so should I assign IP that is not in DHCP range something like `192.168.55.50` or I should use IP within DHCP range?

It's working either way so which one is the best practice?

Comment: Use DHCP reservations then you always get the same address, but do not need to statically configure it.

Comment: Right, now I realize both method has their own usage and should be used according.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both will work. You probably want to assign an static IP from outside the DHCP range though, so that if you ever change the network hardware in your PC (MAC address), it will still have the right IP.

Comment: I'm not quite sure why it still have the same IP if the MAC address is new ?